# Submit form via hidden submit

Tags: jquery, html, event-handling, jquery-ui-dialog

Here is my problem.

I have a project where if a user clicks on a input button, I use jQuery UI dialog to display a message to the user.  If the person presses the 'OK' button I want to trigger the 'hidden' input submit button on the page (line 15/16).  [I have included a jsfiddle example.]

```
<input type="submit" id="ui-lock-btn-hdn" name="lock" value="locked" class="ui-helper-hidden"/>
... {
   $('#ui-lock-btn-hdn').trigger('click');
}
```

jQuery version 1.6.4
jQuery UI version 1.8.11
http://jsfiddle.net/jtoepfer/Xve8z/

I'm not looking to just submit the form via $('form')[0].submit().  I really want to know a) why I cannot submit the form by triggering the click on the hidden submit and b) why this does not work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not just do a `$('#testForm').submit();` instead?

Comment: You're essentially wanting to submit the form programmatically, (instead of having the user click an actual button).  Do what @j08691 pointed out to do so.

Comment: Is there a reason why I cannot trigger the hidden submit button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you don't want to just submit the form directly, but it looks like the behavior you want should work fine with newer versions of jQuery, but not the one your jsfiddle is set to. Changing it to 2.x seems to submit fine for me.

> Looks like somewhere between 1.4.4 and 1.7 they fixed the problem

From http://forum.jquery.com/topic/click-on-submit-button-doesn-t-trigger-form-s-jquery-submit-handler

Comment: PherricOxide,  Thanks.  I've been searching jQuery for some sort of answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do this instead of triggering your button click.

```
$('#testForm').submit();
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Xve8z/23/

Comment: I would like to trigger the hidden submit button in the DOM and have it submit the form.